# What is the reason that epsilon delta definition says the result of multiplying upper bound and $|x-a|$ is less than $\epsilon$?

Tags: limits, analysis, proof-writing, definition, epsilon-delta

In epsilon delta definition when we want to prove a limit like $x^2$ at $x = 2$, we should find the upper bound of $|x+2|$ by assuming a random and small value for delta like $1$. next we say the upper bound times $|x-2|$ is less than $\epsilon$. How can we say this? we just know $|x-2||x+2| < \epsilon$ and $|x-2||x+2|<5|x-2|$. But how do we know $5|x-2| < \epsilon$?  I hope I have asked my question correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to typeset your formulae. Proper punctuation, e.g. capitalizing "I", no extra spaces between punctuation marks, etc. help make the post more readable as well.

Comment: The reason you can conclude $5|x-2|<\epsilon$ is that you choose $\delta$ small enough to ensure this. If you choose $\delta<\frac{\epsilon}{5}$ then $5|x-2|<5\delta<5\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{5}=\epsilon$.

Comment: I'm not sure we say any of those things.  It sounds like you have a weak grasp on the concept of $\epsilon, \delta$ proofs (which isn't uncommon as they are subtle and seldom taught well).  I think it'd be best if you asked these question of you instructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We *don't* know that $5|x-2|<\varepsilon$. What we say here is: if we want to have $5|x-2|<\varepsilon$, that's the same thing as having $|x-2|<\frac\varepsilon5$ and then, in order to get that, we take $\delta=\frac\varepsilon5$, because then$$|x-2|<\delta\implies5|x-2|<\varepsilon.$$